# Multiplayer between iOS9 and iOS10

Tags: ipad, game-center, ios

- One of my friends, Alice, has an **iPad 2nd** gen with **iOS9.3.5** installed on it.
- My other friend, Bob, has an **iPad 4th** gen, recently **iOS10.0.1** installed on it.

The Game Center app was removed when Bob upgraded to **iOS10**, and he can't friend Alice or accept her friend request. Alice can't receive the Game Invite Link from Bob because **iOS9** thinks it's an iCloud document, opening it in Safari.

How can Alice and Bob play online multiplayer games (e.g. Super Stickman Golf 2) over the internet together?

Comment: What happens when the link loads in Safari? Anything? Based on what I've read, in iOS 10 the invite would appear as a rich message (basically showing that it's Game Center and allowing launching directly), but it sounds like it should degrade gracefully in that in prior versions, you just get a link (something like https://www.icloud.com/share/0pVZ0ltWfeGmc806iDQMQ8w8A) in Messages that once tapped accepts the invite. At that point you might need to launch the game manually. Has that been tried?

Comment: Bob can try to connect his account on Alice's phone to accept the invite ?

Comment: @Tubedogg It just comes up as a document that iCloud can't open.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Thanks for fixing up the question! They've already tried that; it seems the entire Game Center system is down. Bob thinks it might be an IP block, because Dave's iOS9 device couldn't friend Alice either.